# CSS Background image not displaying in ActionLink in MVC4

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having an issue with the CSS in my ActionLink on the _Layout.cshtml file.

I changed the "Your logo here" text to reflect an image drawn in the background through a CSS class, however it seems to not load the picture..

```
<p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "sitelogo" })</p>
```

The CSS is:

```
.sitelogo {
background: url("../Images/topLogo.png") no-repeat center right;
display: block;
height: 84px;
width: 585px;
```

The box is displayed in a block with the height and width dimensions, however the picture doesn't display, yet if I use FireBug inspect CSS it pulls the image when I mouse-over the URL in the CSS just fine. Am I missing something painfully obvious with this?

Comment: i was getting same error and it was pretty simple it because you& i copied the site css from default mvc 4.0 application and in there background:none...........                                                                              . site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the pathing is correct? The URL you specify in CSS is relative to that CSS file.

CssFolder 
            styles.css 
ImagesFolder 
       image.png

Alternatively you could use url.content to ensure you're taking the right path:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    " ", 
    "Index", 
    "Home", 
    new { 
        style = "background: url('" + Url.Content("~/Images/yourimage.png") + "') no-repeat center right; display:block; height:84px; width:585px;" 
    }
)
```

Comment: I actually double checked this by putting the DIRECT path (C:/) still nothing. But I'll try the above code.

Comment: For some reason, that worked just fine, but in the CSS it doesn't like it.

Comment: Did the image display or did the css did not work on the webpage?

Comment: The image displays using the Above code. However, if I try and use a class in the CSS, it won't display.. Even though the locations exactly the same.

Comment: Yea, I believe when you deploy the web app some virtual directories are created. They may not have the same folder structure as in your solution. This could possibly cause the images to not be displayed

Answer (score 2):

You can change a little bit the html to achieve that as well:

Replace this

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "sitelogo" })
```

With this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <img alt="your logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/<YOUR LOGO>")" />
</a>
```

Hope this helps