# MVC4 Image on Action Link not Display after Deploy

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using CSS to display image on `@Html.ActionLink`

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WPSWorklog.Models.WorkList>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Work List";
}

<h2>Work List</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "WorkList", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <table class="table-header1">
        <tr>
        <td>
            @{ 
                if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <!-- @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") -->
                    <input type="button" value="New Record" onclick="location.href= './Worklist/Create' " />
                }
             }
        </td>
        <td style="width:80%;text-align:right">
            Find by requester: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { style = "width: 100px; height: 15px" })
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<table id="data-list">
    <tr>
        <th class="ms-standardheader"></th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Requester", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RequesterSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("WPS", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PICSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Doc # / Name", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DmDocNumberSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Work Type", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.WorkTypeSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SubmitDateTimeSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Start", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StartDateTimeSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Finish", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FinishDateTimeSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.WorkStateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th class="ms-standardheader">
            @Html.ActionLink("Remark", "Index", 
                new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RemarkSortParm })
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Only Admin can edit or delete record -->
            @{ if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.WorkListID }, new { @class = "edit_link", title = "Edit" }) @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.WorkListID }, new { @class = "delete_link", title = "Delete" })
                }
            }
            <!-- other users can only see the detail -->
                @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id = item.WorkListID }, new { @class = "details_link", title = "View" })
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Requester.Initial)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PIC.Initial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DmDocNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkType.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubmitDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FinishDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkState.Description)
        </td>
         <td>
            <label title="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remark)" style="text-align:center">&nbsp;...&nbsp;</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount (@Model.TotalItemCount record(s))

@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )
```

Site.css

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    a:hover {
        background-color: #c7d1d6;
    }

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;

}

.float-right {
    float: right;

}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#body {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }



header .content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 20px; 
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-hhp {
    background-image:url("../Images/hhp.png");
}

/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display:block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;

}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #bbb;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */
.featured {
    background-color: #fff;
}

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        background-color: #DADA7A;
        /* 
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
            */
        color: #3e5667;
        padding: 20px 40px 30px 40px;
    }

        .featured hgroup.title h1, .featured hgroup.title h2 {
            color: #fff;
        }

        .featured p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #loginForm input {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #loginForm input[type="checkbox"],
    #loginForm input[type="submit"],
    #loginForm input[type="button"],
    #loginForm button {
        width: auto;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

#socialLoginList button {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#logoutForm {
    display: inline;
}

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em 0.25em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}

.table-title1 {
    display:block;
    padding:0 0.25em 0 0.25em;
    margin-top: 5px; 
}

.table-header1 {
    width: 95% ;
}
/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            color:antiquewhite;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }

    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
    /* Baker & McKenzie stylesheet
        -----------------------------------------------*/

    .bm-banner a:hover{
    color: #a71930;
    }

    td.bm-banner {
        padding:0;
        vertical-align:top;
        background-image:url("../Images/hhp.png") ;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:right top; 
    }

    div.bm-banner{
        position:relative;
        height:100px;
    }

    div.bm-logolink{
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        height:85px;
        left:6px;
    }
    a.bm-logoLinkGif{
        display:block;
        height:80px;
        width:90px;
        float:left;
    }

    img.bm-logoAmimatedGif{
        width:90px;
        height:80px;
        float:left;
    }

    div.bm-globalright{
        position:absolute;
        top:45px;
        right:10px;
    }

    div.bm-breadcrumb{
        position:absolute;
        top:65px;
        left:102px;
        font-size:10pt;
        color:#888;
    }

    div.bm-breadcrumb a {
        color: #6773b6;
    }

    .ms-bannerframe, .ms-GRHeaderBackground {
        background-image: url("../Images/bm-bannerContainerGrad.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position: 2px top;
    }

/* icon
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.add_link {
    background: url("../Images/add.png") no-repeat center ;
    display:grid;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
}

.edit_link {
    background: url("../Images/edit.png") no-repeat center;
    display:inline-block;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}

.delete_link {
    background: url("../Images/trash.png") no-repeat center;
    display:inline-block;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}

.details_link {
    background: url("../Images/details.png") no-repeat center;
    display:inline-block;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
}

.display-label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The problem is after I deploy to production, the image not showing.
I already search and found this link

[CSS Background image not displaying in ActionLink in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311481/css-background-image-not-displaying-in-actionlink-in-mvc4)

but the solution is not suitable for me, because it's defined inside ActionLink not in Site.css

Update: The icon is displayed but its position is less tidy
[image]

Comment: Check if you have right path to image on producation.

Comment: Also, check that the image was uploaded to production.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta image already uploaded to production 
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\Images"

Comment: @OleksiiAza I think the path is correct, if change the code to

Html.ActionLink("E", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeID }, new { class = "edit_link", title = "E" })

the image displayed but with text 'E'

Comment: what if you change display:inline-table to display:block?

Comment: thank you @OleksiiAza, it works, but the link become vertical. So I change to inline-block, it's ok but distance between the link is a bit tenuous. I'm not expert in CSS but could you tell me how to set the distance? and why it's not working with inline-table?

Comment: Try to set margin-left or margin-right property to distance appropriate for your needs.

Comment: @OleksiiAza I have set margin-left and right but the icon is still less tidy, as attached

Comment: Is there any chance you could post your current html and css that you have in browser after page loads?

Comment: @OleksiiAza I already update the html code and css. Actually I'm using default Site.css from MVC 4 with some modification (add logo and image on link)

Answer (score 0):

I know that problem: usually I simply forgot to put the image into the project in VS. If it is not in there, it will not be deployed but nevertheless it shows up on my development server, because it is available on my dev machine.

Comment: I'm not forgot to put image into project in VS, it's already there

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-position in CSS:

```
background-position: center center;
```

You can play around with those values to get it to look right.

Comment: I added background-position and the display still same. fyi, I updated the full site.css

Answer (score 0):

I've come across same issue for cloud deployment. This is how I solved it.

**Follow these steps :**

> 1. I you can try publishing it on your local machine IIS.
> 2. Make sure your the image is present in the published file.
> 3. If the Published folder contains the file. Try deploying the local publish onto the live server and check it will show you the image or
>      not.